# How can I use wobbly windows effect on Cinnamon?

Tags: compiz, cinnamon

I would like to know if possible, then how to achieve 
Wobbly Windows and cube on Cinnamon GUI ?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 minimal with cinnamon 
MDM is the login manager i use.

Comment: There is a good solution as a extension: [http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/extensions/view/24](http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/extensions/view/24) there are some bugs but it is a great extension

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To put it simply, you can't. Cinnamon uses a custom Window Manager called Muffin, which does not feature the wobbly windows and cube of Compiz. It may be possible to achieve these with a plugin, but you would have to write it yourself or ask someone on the Mint forums to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the update.. have u any idea if mint community has already started with this development?? is this related only to muffin?? Can I achieve this if I use some other WM instead of Muffin (or side-by-side to it) ??

Comment: @Z9iT I don't believe they _will_, because one of the reasons Muffin exists is most likely because of the dislike for Compiz and its effects that exists in the Linux community. It is not possible to achieve this with another Window manager on Cinnamon, unfortunately. If you want Wobbly Windows and a Cube, you **have** to use Compiz or Kwin.

Comment: Just to clarify, Cinnamon and Muffin are forks of Gnome Shell and Mutter, respectively, so they are tightly coupled.

Comment: so accouding to your second last comment, does it implicate that its gonna be really long to see woobly windows and cube, etc in cinnamon.. however i've observed that compiz manager installs and opens up flawlessly.. even i can configure the woobly windows in that and no error comes.. however cannot experience the woobly windows.. is using mate a better option in addition to cinnamon ??

Answer (score 3):

There is a wobbly windows extension here:

http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/extensions/view/24

Comment: Why did he get downvoted? This actually works with a few config tricks. I upvoted making this -1 instead of -2

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you cannot. If you want compiz like effects there are extensions out there that can do that for you. I was able to get my alt-tab switcher to look similar to compiz with an extension. Unfortunately I haven't seen any that can do cube or wobbly windows. You can get extensions at the cinnamon website. I may write a cube and wobbly windows extension when I do start learning Java script. I am still learning python. So it is possible you just need to wait for an extension to roll around. But running compiz on cinnamon is impossible. If you want your compiz effects try Unity MATE GNOME Classic KDE, or XFCE if you want to spend hours working. (Watch spatry's cup of Linux and his mint 13 xfce bootcamp to get the compiz effects working on xfce.)

Comment: Did you try this in reality? `compiz --replace` used to replace every metacity, xfwm4 etc.